# Which Address we are sending mails from for sp_send_dbmail

Tags: t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

I did not put sender parameter for sp_send_dbmail (the method which sends email to user). I checked the code but could not find the sender as well. From which address, sp_send_dbmail sends email from ? Do you know transact sql's this method ?

Thank you for your helps.

Cheers
Tonyukuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main sending from Database Mail account

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sysmail-add-account-sp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017